# Validation Rule does not work with Read-Only field

Tags: page-layout, validation-rule, checkbox

I have two checkbox fields on my Opportunity.
I have a Validation Rule `AND(checkboxOne__c = FALSE, checkboxTwo__c = FALSE)` which will throw an error on save, if none is selected: "`Please check at least one checkbox`".
On the Record Page Layout, I set `checkboxOne__c` to Read-Only.
Now even if the Read-Only checkbox (`checkboxOne__c`) is checked, and `checkboxTwo__c` is not checked, the validation rule will nevertheless fire and throw the error on save.
This of course does not happen to Admin Accounts as the Read-Only field is not Read-Only.

If I make the field not Read-Only, then it works for other Profiles etc as well.

Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Where the message are been displayed? ín the top of the screen or in the field?

Comment: Top of the screen because the field to be displayed at needs to be selected. And it can be either or, so I figured better on top.

Comment: With a message like that, it'd probably be more user friendly to use two validation rules and put one error on each field, so that if you add more boxes in the future, users won't get confused. That said, I'm not sure why this error would happen when the field is read-only. You may want to consider contacting support.